# How to colour rows by multiple conditions on DT datatable

Tags: html, r, r-markdown, dt

I've been struggling with this one, and I can't seem to find a solution for it online.

I'm creating an html table using the DT package and I would like to colour the rows depending on several conditions from multiple columns.

Here's an example of the datatable I'm working with:

```
dt <- data.table(id = c("FR12", "FR02", "TR06", "FR07", "FR06", "FR77", "FR14", "FR53", "FR25", "FR59"),
                 method1 = c("Y", "Y", "Y", "Y", "Y", "Y", "Y", "Y", "Y", "Y"),
                 method2 = c("Y", "Y", "Y", "Y", "Y", "Y", "Y", "Y", "Y", NA),
                 method3 = c("Y", NA, "Y", NA, "Y", "Y", "Y", "Y", "Y", NA),
                 method4 = c("Y", NA, NA, NA, NA, "Y", "Y", "Y", NA,  NA)
                 )
```

I'm creating a data table using the following code:

```
  datatable(dt,
  options = list(paging = TRUE,   
                 pageLength = 10, 
                 scrollX = TRUE,  
                 scrollY = TRUE,   
                 autoWidth = FALSE, 
                 server = TRUE,  
                 dom = 'Bfrtip',
                 buttons = c('csv', 'excel')),
  extensions = 'Buttons',
  selection = 'single', 
  filter = 'bottom',            
  rownames = TRUE)
```

I managed to colour rows in which all columns have a "Y" using the following code:

```
datatable(dt,
  options = list(paging = TRUE,   
                 pageLength = 10, 
                 scrollX = TRUE,  
                 scrollY = TRUE,   
                 autoWidth = FALSE, 
                 server = TRUE,  
                 dom = 'Bfrtip',
                 buttons = c('csv', 'excel')),
  extensions = 'Buttons',
  selection = 'single', 
  filter = 'bottom',            
  rownames = TRUE) %>%
formatStyle(c("method1", "method2", "method3", "method4"), target = 'row', 
              backgroundColor = styleEqual(c("Y", NA), c('green', 'white')))
```

But what I would like, is to use a colour gradient, from green to red, to colour depending on the number of columns containing a "Y" value.

Thank you in advance for your help!

Comment: something [like that](https://laustep.github.io/stlahblog/posts/TempCitiesUSA.html)?

Comment: Hello and thank you for your reply! Something like that, but I would like to colour an entire row, depending on the combinations of "Y" for the multiple methods' columns: Say, rows with 4 "Y", green; 3 "Y", yellow; 2 "Y", light orange; 1 "Y", dark orange; 0 "Y", red.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```r
library(DT)

df <- data.frame(
  id = c("FR12", "FR02", "TR06", "FR07", "FR06", "FR77", "FR14", "FR53", "FR25", "FR59"),
  method1 = c("Y", "Y", "Y", "Y", "Y", "Y", "Y", "Y", "Y", "Y"),
  method2 = c("Y", "Y", "Y", "Y", "Y", "Y", "Y", "Y", "Y", NA),
  method3 = c("Y", NA, "Y", NA, "Y", "Y", "Y", "Y", "Y", NA),
  method4 = c("Y", NA, NA, NA, NA, "Y", "Y", "Y", NA,  NA)
)

# get number of Ys in each row
nY <- apply(df[, 2:5], 1L, function(x) length(na.omit(x)))

# colors
clrs <- c(
  "0" = "#ff0000", 
  "1" = "#ff8c00", 
  "2" = "#fab57f", 
  "3" = "#ffff00", 
  "4" = "#00ff00"
)

# colors column
colcol <- clrs[as.character(nY)]

# add four columns each equal to nY - they will be hidden
df2 <- cbind(df, nY, nY, nY, nY)

# datatable
library(DT)
datatable(
  df2, rownames = FALSE,
  options = list(
    columnDefs = list( # hide the nY columns
      list(targets = 5:8, visible = FALSE)
    )
  )
) %>% formatStyle(
  c("method1", "method2", "method3", "method4"), 
  valueColumns = 6:9,
  backgroundColor = styleEqual(nY, colcol)
)
```

[image]

Comment: Amazing stuff! Thank you so much for the ingenious solution!